# The meaning of "a fast-landing"

Tags: meaning

> stock market volatility and concerning signs of a fast-landing by the
>   Chinese economy have stoked voices calling for a delay in the Fed’s
>   tightening cycle.​

I'm not sure about the meaning of the phrase, **'a fast-landing'** in the above sentence.

Comment: The hyphen seems odd. I would expect a noun after the adjective "fast-landing".  I would not expect to see "fast-landing" itself used as a noun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Fast-landing* is an idiomatic expression used to refer to a possible  *quick deceleration* in the rate of growth of China economy.

'*[Hard landing](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/hardlanding.asp)*' is another common expression:

> - An economic state wherein the economy is slowing down sharply or is tipped into outright recession after a period of rapid growth, due to government attempts to rein in inflation. A hard landing may be the undesirable consequence of efforts by a nation's central bank to tighten monetary policy, so as to slow down growth and keep inflation in check. While a soft landing is generally the objective of such tightening measures, a hard landing may be the occasional - and unfortunate - result.

(Investopedia)

Comment: Seems like you could use a citation for your actual answer, not for the answer to a question that wasn't asked.